# how check if port is currently used with IIS7 (webSite) in code behind?

Tags: c#, iis, web, port, servermanager

I developed a program "installer" that will add and configure a new website on IIS.
My problem is that I want to check if the port given by the user is already used by another site before installing.

My project is in C # WinForm style.
Someone you have an idea?

```
string[] lPorts = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames(); ?
```

Comment: IIS ports and serial ports share the name "port", but beyond that, there's no relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this:

[BindingInformation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.binding.bindinginformation%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): Gets or sets the binding information for the current binding.

The value of this property is a colon-delimited string that includes the IP address, port, and host name of the binding. You can leave the host name blank. You can set the IP address to "*" to indicate that the binding works for all variables.

For example, a binding that is set for all IP addresses on port 80 and has no specified host name returns "*:80:" from this property. A binding that is set for IP address 192.168.1.150 on port 8080 returns "192.168.1.150:8080:". A binding that is set for all IP addresses on port 80 for a host named "microsoft.com" returns "*:80:microsoft.com".

The BindingInformation property values are maintained in the ApplicationHost.config file.

Also, you can check this: **[Get IIS bindings at runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2011/01/21/get-iis-bindings-at-runtime-without-being-an-administrator.aspx)**

```
foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement binding in mySite.GetCollection("bindings"))
        {
            string protocol = (string)binding["protocol"];
            string bindingInfo = (string)binding["bindingInformation"];

            if (protocol.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                string[] parts = bindingInfo.Split(':');
                if (parts.Length == 3)
                {
                    //Get the port in use HERE !!!
                    string port = parts[1];
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(protocol, port);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank's a lot !! this is the great response ^^

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the 
[Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) namespace

You should use `ServerManager.Sites` to get a listing of sites. Take a look at the collection Bindings on each site. Each site may have one or more bindings, i.e. it may be accessed via one or more addresses / ports.

Your code above looks for the physical serial ports which where used before usb to connect modems and printers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much! Your answer is totally just as above with the example given. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for C#, but if you need powershell here you go..

Open PowerShell and enter the following:
  import-module webadministration
  get-webbinding