# Proplem with redirect http to https

Tags: c#, http, redirect, ssl, https

In ISS 7.5 i had 2 bindings:

1. - Type: http
   - IP: 127.0.0.1
   - Port: 80
2. - Type: https
   - IP: 127.0.0.1
   - Port: 443

and I using this code redirect http to https: (code in Global.asax.cs file)

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false))
{
  Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
}
```

It's working correctly, but after I changed the 2 bindings in IIS to:

1. - Type: http
   - IP: 127.0.0.1
   - Port: 8101
2. - Type: https
   - IP: 127.0.0.1
   - Port: 8102

It no longer redirect HTTP to HTTPS.  I think this code cannot redirect from port 8101 to port 8102 and I don't know how to get port number of HTTPS in IIS by C#. Please tell how or if you had different solution to redirect.

Comment: Maybe you can check the port of HTTPS binding like this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194394/how-check-if-port-is-currently-used-with-iis7-website-in-code-behind

Answer (score 1):

Can you just simply specify the port in static way like that ?

`Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + ":8102" + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);`

Comment: I think it's not good idea, I wondered if I don't know port number of HTTPS, I can't use code like this :(